# Simple Pygame loads slowly

Tags: python, pygame

I made a little tic tac toe game for my first try at using Pygame, but it takes about 10 seconds to load. Is that normal? If not, how can I make it faster? Link to the code below, sorry if it's a bit messy.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

moves = []
rects = []

# Initialize program
pygame.init()

# Assign FPS a value
FPS = 30
FramePerSec = pygame.time.Clock()

# Setting up color objects
BLUE  = (0, 0, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Setup a 300x300 pixel display with caption
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((300,400))
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe")

def checkWin(c):
    if moves[0] == c and moves[1] == c and moves[2] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[3] == c and moves[4] == c and moves[5] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[6] == c and moves[7] == c and moves[8] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[0] == c and moves[4] == c and moves[8] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[2] == c and moves[4] == c and moves[6] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[0] == c and moves[3] == c and moves[6] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[1] == c and moves[4] == c and moves[7] == c:
        return True
    elif moves[2] == c and moves[5] == c and moves[8] == c:
        return True

    return False

def drawX(rect):
    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (rect.centerx - 25, rect.centery - 25), (rect.centerx + 25, rect.centery + 25), 2)

    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (rect.centerx - 25, rect.centery + 25), (rect.centerx + 25, rect.centery - 25), 2)

    moves.pop(rects.index(rect))
    moves.insert(rects.index(rect), "X")

def drawO(rect):
    moves.pop(rects.index(rect))
    moves.insert(rects.index(rect), 'O')
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, rect.center, 25, 2)

# define a main function
def main():
    # Draw grid
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (i*100, j*100, 100, 100), 2)
            rects.append(pygame.Rect((i*100, j*100), (98, 98)))
            moves.append(' ')

    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 300, 300, 100), 0)
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None,100) # use default system font, size 100
    mytext = myfont.render("X's Turn", True, WHITE)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(mytext, (25,325))
    pygame.display.update()

    gameOver = False
    xTurn = True
    count = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and gameOver == False:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for rect in rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and moves[rects.index(rect)] == ' ':
                        count += 1
                        if xTurn == True:
                            drawX(rect)
                            if checkWin('X') == False:
                                if count == 9:
                                    mytext = myfont.render("Draw!", True, WHITE)
                                    gameOver = True
                                else:
                                    xTurn = False
                                    mytext = myfont.render("O's Turn", True, WHITE)
                            else:
                                mytext = myfont.render("X Wins!", True, GREEN)
                                gameOver = True
                        elif xTurn == False:
                            drawO(rect)
                            if checkWin('O') == False:
                                if count == 9:
                                    mytext = myfont.render("Draw!", True, WHITE)
                                    gameOver = True
                                else:
                                    xTurn = True
                                    mytext = myfont.render("X's Turn", True, WHITE)
                            else:
                                mytext = myfont.render("O Wins!", True, GREEN)
                                gameOver = True
                        print(moves)
                        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 300, 300, 100), 0)
                        DISPLAYSURF.blit(mytext, (25,325))
                        pygame.display.update()

        FramePerSec.tick(FPS)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # call the main function
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried running in other PC? Maybe if you run it from a SSD it loads faster than a regular HDD

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the tip. I just commented out each line of code to see which one slows it down. I found that pygame.font.SysFont(None,100) takes a long time to run. After some googling, I found that others have this problem on Mac OS as well. I guess there's just no way around it

Comment: Seems like you've figured out a solution. However, just curious, were you also working off a mac? Or does the problem mentioned in the link extend to PC as well?

Comment: @code11 yes, i was working on a mac

Answer (score 2):

I found that the line that took a long time to load was pygame.font.SysFont(None,100), and i found the solution to this problem here: github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/344

After installing XQuartz 2.7.11, it loads much faster